# Migrating data between Payment Gateways

Tags: web-applications, e-commerce, payment-gateway, data-migration, recurring-billing

We are looking to shift payment gateway providers for our e-commerce application; as such we would like to migrate such information as;

- Customer Contracts / Billing Information
- Credit Card Information
- Transactions

from our previous gateway to the new gateway. Are there any best practices or techniques that could be followed or would be recommended for this?

The application supports recurring charges. There is also need to keep PCI compliance in mind when undertaking this exercise.

Any input would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My understanding is that this process is usually initiated by you as the customer of the payment gateways but the process is then completed by the two payment gateways you are migrating between.

Because they should both be PCI compliant they will be able to transfer the data between each other securely.

The gateway that you've migrated to will then be able to supply you a list of mapped card tokens so you can migrate between tokens.

I cannot comment on billing information and transactions as I haven't dealt with these.

Comment: Thanks marshall; you are right the new gateway has confirmed that they would take this up as a migration project which is scoped for our requirement; we would need to provide the card details and the expiry dates which would need to be obtained from the previous gateway. Transaction history cannot be migrated and would remain with the previous gateway. We would need to use our stored database logs to preserve transaction history. From what I see there is going to be some manual work in terms of re-associating cards to the new tokens which are generated.

Comment: Correct. Some payment gateways offer to release the card data in an encrypted form (Stripe is one I believe), but all prefer to stick to transferring B2B.